# Android Light Sensor Returns null

Tags: android

I am developing a project with light sensor, but my problem is that light sensor always return null and my testing device is **samsung galaxy y** . my doubt: is my light sensor code is wrong or my galaxy y does not contains light sensor?

I have tried below code:

```
package com.example.lightsensor;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LightSensorActivity extends Activity {

 ProgressBar lightMeter;
 TextView textMax, textReading;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.light_sensor_layout);
        lightMeter = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.lightmeter);
        textMax = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.max);
        textReading = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.reading);

        SensorManager sensorManager 
        = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        Sensor lightSensor 
        = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT);

        if (lightSensor == null){
         Toast.makeText(LightSensorActivity.this, 
           "No Light Sensor! quit-", 
           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
         float max =  lightSensor.getMaximumRange();
         lightMeter.setMax((int)max);
         textMax.setText("Max Reading: " + String.valueOf(max));

         sensorManager.registerListener(lightSensorEventListener, 
           lightSensor, 
           SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        }
    }

    SensorEventListener lightSensorEventListener
    = new SensorEventListener(){

  @Override
  public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }

  @Override
  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT){
    float currentReading = event.values[0];
    lightMeter.setProgress((int)currentReading);
    textReading.setText("Current Reading: " + String.valueOf(currentReading));
   }
  }

    };
}
```

Can any one help me what's wrong with code or  the device does not contain light sensor?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I think Galaxy Y aren't embedded with light sensor!!

Comment: @K_Anas GALAXY Y not contain's light sensor?

Comment: yes I think so have you checked the technical sheet of galaxy Y?

Comment: look at my answer i have checked the specification for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samsung Galaxy y aren't embedded with light sensor check the samsung specification [here](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_y_s5360-4117.php)

Sensors supported by Samsung galaxy Y are: accelerometer, compass, proximity

[image]